# cant put navbar item on extreme left

Tags: html, css, sass, navbar

I want to make a navbar with main  logo on left and rest on right they are left and right but are still somewhat centered and not going extreme left/right

edit: i think i didnt explain my problem very well the problem is the list items on navbar are not sticking to the extreme left of its container and is somewhat centere

my navbar:

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  line-height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.nav div.logo {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav div.logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
          <a href="#">Your Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div id="mainListDiv" class="main_list">
          <ul class="navlinks">
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <span class="navTrigger">
          <i></i>
          <i></i>
          <i></i>
      </span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried adding `margin:0` and `padding: 0` this is a codepen sample so I know that it stays on left but can understand why it is not staying o left on my code

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Where's the rest of the css?

Answer (score 0):

Why not position them? While I'm not sure exactly what your code is trying to accomplish, if you would like them to be on the extreme left or right, you can assign each a position (values https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp), which then allows you to set a left or right property (see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.asp).